# Dax distinctcount if function not working

Tags: powerpivot, calculated-columns, dax

I have an OR statement that I need to include into a DISTINCTCOUNT statement and.

I need only count if

> IF(OR([acm_auto_category_id] = 1;[acm_manual_category_id] = 1); 1;0)

and then I need to count on a third column. In Tableau the calculated field looks like this:

> COUNTD(IF [manual_category_id] = 1 OR [auto_category_id] = 1 THEN [lead_message_id] END)

So in words I need: To count distinct the number of lead message id's when the if statement is fulfilled and

Currently I have :

> No of distinct :=CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT([lq_lead_message_id];IF(OR([acm_auto_category_id] = 1;[acm_manual_category] = 1);1;0));;)

Answer (score 0):

Think what you are after is:

```
=
  CALCULATE (
      DISTINCTCOUNT ( table[cat_id] ),
      FILTER ( table, table[auto_cat_id] = 1 || table[manual_cat_id] = 1 )
             )
```

Comment: That one did not work. However I now have : =CALCULATE (DISTINCTCOUNT ([lq_lead_message_id]);FILTER (Query;[acm_auto_category_id] = 1 && [acm_manual_category_id] = 1 )
    )  Its count the blank in as well!? How do I get the function to ignore blanks?

Comment: you are right in that the OR needs a FILTER although your current example would give you AND. DISTINCTCOUNT() ignores blanks so maybe your field isn't really blank.